# Make Reactive Kafka work with Confluent Schema Registry Avro Schema

Tags: akka, apache-kafka, avro, reactive

How to make Reactive Kafka (https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka) work with Confluent Schema Registry Avro Schema? Here is my sample code:

```html
def create(groupId: String)(implicit system: ActorSystem): Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, Array[Byte]], Consumer.Control] = {
    
    val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system, new StringDeserializer, new ByteArrayDeserializer)
      .withBootstrapServers(bootstrap)
      .withGroupId(groupId)
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
      .withProperty("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl)
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[String].getName)
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[KafkaAvroDeserializer].getName)
      .withProperty(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true")
    
    Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(createDataSetJobRequestTopic))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure the consumer to use the Confluent deserializer : `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class`

Set the following properties :

- **ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG**
- **ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG**

In addition, you have to add the property "**schema.registry.url**" in order to specify at least one address pointing to your schema registry instance.

Finally, you have to add the following dependecy to your project :

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${io.confluent.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

[Confluent Documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html)

Comment: Thanks, I know how to consume kafka avro message with schema registry, the problem I asked is how to use it with reactive kafka. It requires to construct consumerSettings first like my pasted code above. I didn't know if it possible to get Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, AvroClass] directly because KafkaAvroDeseriablizer is not generic. Otherwise I got CommittableMessage[String, Object] and then cast it to specific one?

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure this out. I am having the exact problem of deserializing kafka messages through akka streams kafka. It returns an object which I am unable to cast to my type.

Comment: It seems the issue was not fixed and reported by others. https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/issues/342.